# CakePHP MySQL virtual field problem

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm trying to order my results in a slightly complicated way.  I've created a virtualfield called 'priority' to order results by. Here's my code:

```
    public $virtualFields = array(
    'priority'=>'(Venue.featured * 5000) + (Venue.views * 2) + ((Venue.image_count > 0) * 500)',
);
```

Now this always returns just the value of ((Venue.image_count > 0) * 500), ie either 500 or 0.  If I remove that part of the field, leaving:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'priority'=>'(Venue.featured * 5000) + (Venue.views * 2)',
);
```

The expected result is given.  I also wish to add another component to the field, which has the same effect.  Code:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'priority'=>'(Venue.featured * 5000) + (Venue.views * 2) + ((CHAR_LENGTH(Venue.blurb) > 0) * 500)',
);
```

In this case, again, the field is only ever 500 or 0, not the full value of all the fields.

I don't understand what's going on!  If I create a virtual field that either measure image_count or CHAR_LENGTH(Venue.blurb), it works fine, but adding either of these to the other parts of the field make it fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax for both `((Venue.image_count > 0) * 500)` and `((CHAR_LENGTH(Venue.blurb) > 0) * 500)` are incorrect.

You should use an [`IF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) statement:

```
IF(Venue.image_count > 0, 500, 0)
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(Venue.blurb) > 0, 500, 0);
```

**For example:**

```
public $virtualFields = array(
  'priority' => '(Venue.featured * 5000) + (Venue.views * 2) + IF(Venue.image_count > 0, 500, 0)',
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's fixed it. Any idea why ((Venue.image_count > 0) * 500) returns 0 or 500 on its own, though?